# Create multiple collections in mongodb using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to create multiple collections in MongoDB using pymongo module as below. But its been failing.

```
import pymongo
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
mydb = client.tstdata # connect/create a db in mongodb
list1 = ["tst-1","tst-2","tst-3"] # list of collections to be created
for each_val in list1:
    print (each_val)
    col = mydb.each_val #create collection
    col.insert_one({"name" : "test"})
```

Instead of creating multiple collections using values in 'each_val' variable, its just creating collection with "each_val" name; how can I fix the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the syntax:

```
col = mydb[each_val]
```

The drivers do their best to (sort of) match the mongo shell. So `db.x.insert` will insert into collection x rather than any variable named x as you have seen.

Comment: When I use the above method its creating only the last collection from the list; In above case i can see only tst-3 collection in MongoDB; How can I fix it?

Comment: After making everything in one line as you mentioned db.x.insert method its working fine Thanks Belly Buster

Answer (score 0):

according to your code, you are creating each_val collection
you have to add collection name in square brackets in pymongo **[ ]**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
mydb = client.tstdata # connect/create a db in mongodb
list1 = ["tst-1","tst-2","tst-3"] # list of collections to be created
for each_val in list1:
    print (each_val)
    col = mydb[each_val] #create collection
    col.insert_one({"name" : test})
```

Comment: When I use the above method its creating only the last collection from the list; In above case i can see only tst-3 collection in MongoDB

Comment: it will list all three Collection.just one change enclose test in quotes "test".  in mongo shell execute  use tstdata; and db.getCollectionNames()